# Flutter background locator | Unable to get location in release mode (Android) using flutter package Background locator

Tags: flutter, dart, location

I am using the flutter package for capturing user's location in background even when the application is killed.
It is working fine in debug mode but cannot respond in release mode.
Please find below link for the information.

https://github.com/rekabhq/background_locator

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution? I am facing the exact same issue.